# xlwings (python) - How to activate a sheet?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am just wondering how to make a sheet active.If I operate a .xlsx file with xlwings,I hope one particular sheet(eg. sheets[2]) will defaultly show when I open it in Excel next time.I know how to do it in Excel software——just click the sheet tag and save the file,but what should I do with xlwings?Thanks a lot!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aR1pf.jpg)

Comment: `wb.sheets["Sheet2"].activate()`?

Answer (score 1):

OK,just use the sheet.select() and save the workbook.